# How do machine learning models treat nonlinear predictors?

Tags: machine-learning, predictor, nonlinearity

How do machine learning models (including neural networks) respond to the presence of a nonlinear attribute among predictors in a training set?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "nonlinear attribute". Are you saying there is a _nonlinear relationship_ observed between the attribute and the response? We can guess that that's what you mean, but as it is currently written the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Yes, one of the attributes has a non-linear relationship to the response.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by machine learning. Smoothing splines are used to model non-linear effects and the properties of the regression function (e.g., the smoothness of the regression function) are often determined through cross validation. I would consider that falling into the same category as what many people mean when they refer to machine learning.

Comment: Within my domain (task area) the term "machine learning", I assume, means the ability to predict the value of response (dependent variable) based on a training set with several attributes (predictors).

Comment: Then yes smoothing splines would fall into that category and appears responsive to your query about non-linear covariate effects.